# How to find upper and lower bound

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, bounds, norm

Let $\Sigma \in S_{++}^n$ be a symmteric positive definte matrix with all diagonal entries one. Let $U \in R^{n \times k_1}$, $W \in R^{n \times k_2}$, $\Lambda \in R^{k_1 \times k_1}$ and $T \in R^{k_2 \times k_2}$, where $\Lambda$ and $T$ are both diagonal matrix with positive elements, and $n > k_2 > k_1$. We also know $\text{trace}(\mathbf{\Lambda}) = \mu \times \text{trace}(\mathbf{T})$ and sum of absolute values of all the elements of $U$ is less than $W$. Then how can I find upper and lower bound on-

\begin{align*}
\frac{\|\Sigma -  UTU^\top\|_F^2}{\|\Sigma -  W\Lambda W^\top\|_F^2}
\end{align*}

in terms of $\mu$, $W$, $\Lambda$ and $\Sigma$. I have asked the same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3863599/how-to-find-upper-and-lower-bound

Comment: Please do not cross-post your question unless you are prepared to transfer all useful answers that appear on one site to the other site.